# I have a list of numbers around 400k and I want to delete 16k random numbers from that list

Tags: python, list

Here is my Python script below but it just returning one of the lists. either it return 400k list of numbers or 16k list of numbers but it is not giving me a filterd  result what am I doing wrong?

```
import os

# Read in the original and new file          
orig = open('original.csv','r')
new = open('new.csv','r')

#in new but not in orig
bigb = set(new) - set(orig)

# To see results in console if desired
print(bigb)

# Write to output file    

with open('different.csv', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in bigb:
        file_out.write(line)

#close the files  
orig.close()    
new.close()    
file_out.close()
```

Comment: Can you share more details? Is there a list of numbers you want to delete from this larger list? Do you have some rule for deletion, like delete every nth number or every number divisible by xx?

Comment: There are all random numbers. Approx 16625 numbers which I want to delete from the given list of numbers from 70000 - 347862. No rule just random numbers.

Comment: Edit your question and add more details, maybe even share a spreadsheet link so members can access and understand your need. Explain whether you want to do this from a function, which numbers you want to remove, if there is a pattern on those numbers to be removed, or if you are going to create a one-column list for those numbers to be removed. ```If you leave your question like that, others will deny your question and it will end up being closed!```

Comment: I updated the question I hope it is clear.

Comment: column it is I have updated the question

Comment: Maybe sort list B then you can do a fast lookup

Comment: I did but this is just an example my real list is huge https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cWTBNtCAj-FJ17Ou1UGwj11nR81JOKdoIrOWR-_K7cM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

try in column C if column A is your list A and column B is your list B:

```
=FILTER(A:A; A:A<>""; NOT(REGEXMATCH(A:A&""; "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^"; 1; B:B)&"$"))
```

[image]

---

### update 1:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(A:A, NOT(COUNTIF(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(
 INDIRECT("B1:B"&MAX((B1:B<>"")*(ROW(B1:B))))&"", "\d+")*1), A:A))))
```

### update 2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1:A, {REGEXEXTRACT(
 INDIRECT("B1:B"&MAX((B1:B<>"")*(ROW(B1:B))))&"", "\d+")*1, IF(
 INDIRECT("B1:B"&MAX((B1:B<>"")*(ROW(B1:B))))="",,0)}, 2, 0), A1:A), 
 "where Col1 <> 0"))
```

Comment: can you do this with this data. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cWTBNtCAj-FJ17Ou1UGwj11nR81JOKdoIrOWR-_K7cM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @RobinMalhotra yes, answer & your sheet updated

Comment: bro Thanks a lot but why is it starting from 86604? Like in this List B subtracted from list A = Output. and it should be from 70000 why 86604 ?

Comment: Bro can you help out please